# Why won't Allegro initialize?

Tags: c++, allegro

I tried installing allegro 5 to code blocks, but even though it seems the program compiles it won't initialize. I get an error saying the application failed to start because allegro-5.0.9-monolith-md-debug.dll was not found. It also says re-installing may help, but I've tried that several times already. I tried following online tutorials, but I still get this error. Am I doing something wrong? Please help.

Comment: Copy the .dll file to the location of your .exe file.

Comment: I tried that already. In fact, I tried copying all the dll files in allegro under 'bin' into the same location as the .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Copy allegro-5.0.9-monolith-md-debug.dll into the same directory as your source code. I had this same exact problem. I was using Visual C++ 2010 express edition, paste it with the source not the .exe if you are running it from within the compiler, if you want to run it outside of the compiler it will need to in the same location as the .exe